# Meteor - package accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown has an empty div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteorite

I'm currently playing around with Meteor and Meteorite and several of their packages. Currently I am trying to create a simple login using "accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown" however even though I'm using "{{loginButtons}}" and the server is throwing no errors, all I am getting is an empty div element, like so:

```
<div id="login-buttons" class="login-buttons-dropwdown-align-right"></div>
```

I know the code is fine, as I have it running on a Mac OS without any issues, however this environment is Ubuntu using Chrome.

Why is this and how do I go about rectifying it?

The only thing I can think of is that I am running Ubuntu through VirtualBox.

Comment: I'm confused. You have a meteor project on OS X which works when you browse to it. You cloned the project on an Ubuntu VM and when run and browsed to there the login buttons do not load. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sneaky one, since there's not a lot of definition in your question, like for instance what packages do you have installed, are you using meteorite etc.  However, a very likely cause is that you are somehow clobbering bootstrap or haven't included it in the main meteor packages.  Check inside your .meteor/packages to see if you have installed bootstrap.

if you haven't then install bootstrap via:

```
meteor install bootstrap
```

from the main  project directory.

Otherwise make sure you haven't included some other package or javascript that clobbers the namespace.  For instance, having another copy of bootstraps dropdown.js will cause an empty div.

Also be aware that few if any packages are designed for bootstrap 3 at the moment and it will break your dropdown as well, especially in the new 6.5.0 release.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me. I restarted from scratch using the bootstrap install as well and worked fine without an issue, must of done some changes under the hood when I was changing the code.